# What does "drop" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Here is a sentence from [The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/02/07/fashion/what-to-talk-about-at-new-york-fashion-week.html):

> New York Fashion Week officially kicks off on Feb. 8, and along with the usual chatter about the shows comes the showy chatter among industry folk: that under-the-radar label, the **luxe sneaker drop**, the splashy debut.

What does "drop" mean here? I can't find a pertinent definition. I thought "drop" as a noun means "delivery" or "falling."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's recently (AFAIK) become common to refer to the act of releasing a new product release as "dropping", particularly when the product is something that might be eagerly awaited by customers.

This usage seems to have originated in the music industry. For example, you might ask "When will Drake's new album drop?".

Some online sources also show a transitive usage, like, "When will Drake drop his new album?", but I don't recall actually hearing it used this way in real life.

So this quote is talking about the release of a new shoe design.

Comment: There's a bit of discussion [here](https://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=537100) about the emergence of "drop" as meaning "release commercially to the public." There were no definitive findings, but it seems to have originated specifically in the hip-hop community in the 1990s in reference to music tracks or albums.